# creating pl/sql procedure to get different columns from different tables

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, report

I'm trying to create a procedure to get the data from different columns of different tables. I have written this code but I get error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of
the following:
begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
  form
current cursor external language
The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue. can anybody

```
create or replace procedure List_of_mfi
(

cq out sys_refcursor

)
as

begin

    open cq for SELECT a.mfi_name, 
   b.mfi_type_name, 
   c.mfi_tier_name, 
   d.mfi_state_name,
   e.mfi_district_name, 
   a.mfi_phone_no 
   FROM   mfi_master a, 
   mfi_type_master b,mfi_tier_new c,mfi_state_master d,mfi_district_master e
   WHERE  a.mfi_type_id = b.mfi_type_id(+) 
   and a.mfi_tier_id = c.mfi_tier_id(+) 
   and a.mfi_state_id = d.mfi_state_id(+)
   and a.MFI_DISTRICT_ID=e.MFI_DISTRICT_ID(+);
end;

declare
cq  sys_refcursor;
mfi_name varchar2(150);
mfi_type_name varchar2(150);
mfi_tier_name varchar2(150);
mfi_state_name varchar2(150);
mfi_district_name varchar2(150);
mfi_phone_no varchar2(150);
--SELECT a.mfi_name, b.mfi_type_name, c.mfi_tier_name, d.mfi_state_name,e.mfi_district_name, a.mfi_phone_no 


begin
    List_of_mfi(cq);
    loop

     fetch cq into mfi_name,mfi_type_name,mfi_tier_name,mfi_state_name,mfi_district_name,mfi_phone_no;

     EXIT WHEN cq%NOTFOUND;

    --print 
    dbms_output.put_line('mfi_name:'||mfi_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('mfi_type_name:'||mfi_type_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('mfi_tier_name:'||mfi_tier_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('mfi_state_name:'||mfi_state_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('mfi_district_name:'||mfi_district_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('mfi_phone_no:'||mfi_phone_no);

    end loop;
end;
```

Since I'm a beginner I do not know if this code is correct or wrong. I want to find out how to edit this and make it work using oracle reports builder.Thanks everyone.

Comment: try using a `/` after procedure definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> end;
>
> declare
> ```

You must put forward slash **"/"** after the `END` keyword to terminate the **procedure** block before you execute another **PL/SQL anonymous block**.

Put "/" after each END:

```
END;
/
```

Comment: @k1j You're welcome. Please mark it as answered, it would help others.